# Why are nested transactions said to be a poor solution in the Rails documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions

The documentation [1] for active-record transactions gives this code-block:

```
Student.transaction do
  Course.transaction do
    course.enroll(student)
    student.units += course.units
  end
end
```

and says "This is a poor solution, but fully distributed transactions are beyond the scope of Active Record."

Why is this a poor solution?

[1] http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The key part in the documentation relating to that seems to me to be "A transaction acts on a single database connection. If you have multiple class-specific databases, the transaction will not protect interaction among them". If you have a single database connection no issue I would think?

Comment: The best explanation I on Transactions in Rails in this post - http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/ - which has a great section using the official code examples and explaining the issue with nested transactions further.

Comment: Ben, that's indeed a good article but doesn't talk about why nesting transactions as shown "is a poor solution."